# how to authenticate database in mongodb 3.0.2

Tags: mongodb

I am currently working on mongodb database. I need to authenticate the database by username and password. By searching the web I found that by creating user we can set username and password. I tried that by the query .createUser().User is successfully created by the database can be accessed by all .Please help me to access the database to particular users with appropriate username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making use of the connection option '**authSource**' in your connection string.. ?

Below excerpt is taken from the official MongoDB documentation that explains the connection option '**authSource**'
( reference - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ )

> Specify the database name associated with the user’s credentials, if the users collection do not exist in the database where the client is connecting. authSource defaults to the database specified in the connection string.
>
> For authentication mechanisms that delegate credential storage to other services, the authSource value should be $external as with the PLAIN (LDAP) and GSSAPI (Kerberos) authentication mechanisms.
>
> MongoDB will ignore authSource values if the connection string specifies no user name.

Comment: can't understand I need procedure for authenticating a database in mongodb .** My database should respond to queries to authenticated person only .Not to all those queried **. Please help me